# How to get the last line number of Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the last row elements from a CSV file.

My code so far -

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd

temp = pd.read_csv('gs://my-bucket/my_file.csv',header=None)
print(temp[0][6]) -> Key 0 is obvious as the first element in last row but how to get no. 6 dynamically?
```

It prints -

```
BO
```

My sample CSV file -

```
John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
,Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298
"Joan ""the bone"", Anne",Jet,"9th, at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
BO,Testing,6
```

What I want to know that the no. of records in the real file coming in would be changing every day. So how would I get the last row no. without reading the entire file and increment a counter?

Comment: Try `temp.shape[0]` to get number of records in temp after pd.read_csv.

Comment: `temp.iloc[-1]` gives you the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last row of a Dataframe by using the -1 index.

In your example `temp.iloc[-1]`, or `temp.iloc[-1].values` if you want to get the values from the last dataframe row as an array.